# Firebase callable functions fail

Tags: firebase, function, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, callable

Many functions have started to fail intermittently with the following error even before the first line of code is executed:

> FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Failed to parse access token response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 4"."}

It's been more than 5 five days since i had opened a bug issue with Firebase support and i still don't have any feedback.

Does anyone why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

**Libraries used and their versions:**

```
"firebase": "^8.2.9",
"firebase-admin": "^9.5.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
```

**Initializations:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "..."
};
var firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: Can you show the [versions of the SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) as well as how you load the required modules and initialize an admin app instance?

Comment: I've modified the post to answer your questions. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Cloud Function, if you want to interact with the Firebase services (e.g. Firestore, Auth service, etc), you need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin).

So, you need to load the `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` modules, and initialize an `admin` app instance from which you interact with the services, as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const firestoreDB = admin.firestore();
const authService = admin.auth();

// ... 

// Examples:

// In a Cloud Function
return firestoreDB.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
});


// In another Cloud Function
return authService.updateUser(uid, {
   email: 'modifiedUser@example.com',
   phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
})
.then((userRecord) => {
  // ...
  // return ...
})
```

In other words, you don't need to do:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "..."
};
var firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

---

Also note this note from the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started):

> In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the
> latest version of the Firebase CLI and the `firebase-functions` SDK.
> It's a good practice to frequently update both the Firebase CLI and
> the SDK with these commands **inside the functions folder of your**
> **Firebase project**:
>
> `npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save`
>
> `npm install -g firebase-tools`